# AWS API Gateway Wildcard Subdomain

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-api-gateway, gateway

I have developed an application and deployed it to AWS Elastic Beanstalk that I would like to make accessible only through the AWS API Gateway for the purposes of API versioning, throttling, etc... The application uses subdomains as account identifiers in requests (example: http://accountname.example.com). All of my requests are using the HTTP Integration Type and so I simply define the endpoint that I want to pass the request through to.

I cannot seem to figure out how to provide the subdomains provided by the requester to the AWS API Gateway to the application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. In defining the Integration Request on the API Gateway console I do not understand how to give the Endpoint URL a parameter in place of the subdomain that can be replaced with the subdomain provided in the user's request to the API Gateway. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, to clarify... you have the setup working, except for this?  And your objective is to extract the incoming `Host` header and place it into a query string parameter in the integration request?

Comment: It all works except when I make a request I receive the expected response when an invalid subdomain is provided. I need to be able to get the subdomain from the host header and pass that through as the subdomain of the Endpoint URL.

Comment: To try to make things more clear, the endpoints on the elastic beanstalk application work like this (group1.example.com/members) gets members for group 1. (group2.example.com/members) gets members for group 2. I just need that subdomain and I need to add it to the Endpoint URL. I hope I'm making sense. I'm still new to the API Gateway.

Comment: I see where you're going. Not sure how it works with a custom domain, but using a generic `execute-api` domain, I was able to declare the `Host` header in the method request, and then create a `Host` header entry in the integration request, mapping it to `method.request.header.Host`. With that in place, the `Host:` header my server sees on the incoming request is the one I used to reach API Gateway, instead of the one I configured as my endpoint.  Is that similar what you had in mind? To get just the subdomain, you'd have to manipulate substrings, which don't think is possible in headers.

Comment: I see what you mean. I was hoping for a solution that doesn't change the server code at all but that might not be doable. Changing how I get the subdomain from a request won't take but a minute though. I'll have to see how this still works with a custom domain but I think this is the direction I'll go. Thanks!

Comment: @MattClevenger hey, I also have a similar requirement. So can you tell me how you solved this? Maybe you can post it as an answer

Comment: @JerinAMathews I don't think I could adequately answer the question in a way that would satisfy others looking for a true answer but I can tell you what I did to go about it. I ended up not using API Gateway for this purpose. My REST API all went through the gateway but to serve files for each subdomain I just deployed an application on EBS. Wildcard subdomains using Route53 and EBS aren't nearly as much of a headache. It worked out for the best anyway. I was using API Gateway with Serverless for my API and file servers aren't the best Lambda use case because of the cold starts.